# How to create a slider that snaps to a selection

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How would I go about making a slider that snaps to a selection. I was there to be 3 selections, one on the left, one on the right and one in the middle. When the user drags the slider left a little, it will animate and snap to the left selection. The same effect on the right and in the middle.

If you are familiar with the app UBER, they have something (with 4 sections) that is exactly what I am talking about. Screenshot here (slider on the bottom):
 [image: http://i.imgur.com/xTPfDcY.png]

Any idea how I would implement this? Should I use a UISlider or no?

Thanks a lot,
Gabe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without considering the custom appearance of the Uber slider, you can achieve this "animated snapping" behavior by listening for the Touch Up Inside event (and Touch Up Outside, for completeness' sake) on your slider, and setting its value to the nearest integer value:

```
- (IBAction)sliderTouchUp:(UISlider *)sender
{
    [sender setValue:floorf([sender value] + 0.5) animated:YES];
}
```

Setting the minimum value to 1 and the maximum value to 3 will give you three "stops" on the slider, and when the user releases the slider, it will animate to the nearest stop.

Comment: This works. I can't get it to stop in the middle though. What should I put for the value to make it stop in the middle?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In my experiments, it stopped in the middle (with value = 2) when I configured it as I described. Are you referring to it snapping while the user is still dragging? Because my code doesn't do that.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks so much. Next step, custom design. I that even possible with a uislider?

Comment: UISlider has always been skinnable. If you're going for a totally custom look like Uber, you might want to fake it by placing an image view underneath the slider and just customizing the thumb image. The track images really want to be stretchable, and the type of customization that Uber did is not really conducive to being captured by a stretchable image. Better off setting the track images to a totally transparent image and sticking the custom image behind the slider.

Comment: Also, if this answered your question, would you mind clicking the checkmark to accept it as the official answer?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that you want to look at the current value of the slider, as the user moves it, and if it falls within your "snap" range, you set the slider's value to the desired location. Something like this:

```
- (void)sliderUpdated:(UISlider *)slider {
    float val = slider.value;
    if (val>= 0.46 && val <= 0.54) {
        [slider setValue:0.5 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Obviously you will need to check three different ranges. The code I posted makes the slider appear to have a detent in the middle. You probably also need to keep track of which direction the slider is being moved so you know to move the slider to the left or right.

Comment: -1: This doesn't actually duplicate the behavior of the slider in the Uber app, and additionally it causes the slider thumb to wiggle oddly when near the "detent."

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the code is just a rough guideline to give an idea of how to adjust the slider's value based on its current value. In my real use of this code, I don't animate the change of value so it works much better. I posted the code with animation since that is what is wanted in the question.